# One template breaks another, even when it shouldn't match

Tags: xml, xslt

I am newish to XSLT and am boggled by the apparent effect that one template is having on my transformation, even when it shouldn't match anything.

If I have the following xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="flattenText">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="current()"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="flattenText">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$node/node()">
        <xsl:if test="self::text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="self::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="flattenText">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And run it on this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<input>This <span class="blah">text</span> should be flattened.</input>
</root>
```

I get this output, which I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>This text should be flattened.</output>
```

But if I add in this template to the bottom of the XSL file:

```
<xsl:template match="span[@class = 'yuk']">
    <span>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">poo</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>This  should be flattened.</output>
```

The contents of the span go away, even though 1) I'm not applying that template anywhere that I see, and 2) it shouldn't even match the span in the input, because it has class "blah" and the template should only match class "yuk."

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how I can fix it?  I must just be making some dumb mistake.

I'm using the JAXP (com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl) transformer in Oxygen XML Editor 16.1, but I have the same problem in Eclipse.  Saxon 6.5.5 works, but I can't use that for my project.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I appreciate everyone's help and attempts to reproduce my problem.  My colleague was able to reproduce it, so I still think something is truly going wrong.  In case anyone's interested, here's some info on my situation:

- Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64-bit, Service Pack 1
- java -version: java version "1.8.0_31"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
- I get this warning when I run JAXP transformations in Oxygen: "
   
  [JAXP] WARNING: 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.'"  I don't know if that is important or not.

I'm working on an old codebase that's set up to use the JAXP transformer.  There's a tight and rigid timeline to get this work done, and I think switching to Saxon right now would entail too much change and risk.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Adding the said template does **not** change the output. Tested with [Xalan 2.7.1](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqg/1), libxslt and Saxon.  -- P.S. I believe your stylesheet is unnecessarily complicated - but that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce: oXygen 15.2 with various XSLT processors; SaxonHE9-5-1-2J directly.    Suspect user error.   Check console/logs for errors and make sure you're not looking at stale output.

Comment: Why can you only use JAXP for your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, the result you are getting makes no sense, but your `flattenText` template is pretty unnecessary. You can replace this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="flattenText">
     <xsl:with-param name="node" select="current()"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

with this:

```
<!-- Will work the same as flattenText current node is an element -->
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

and delete the `flattenText` template. Perhaps that would eliminate your issue.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This was the most helpful answer.  My actual code situation was a bit more complicated, but I was able to incorporate your suggestion, and that seems to have circumvented the problem.  I didn't realize value-of would get the text of nested elements.

Comment: @tookie_styles Yeah, that's how the [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes) of an element is defined, and `value-of` outputs the string-value of whatever it selects: _"The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order."_

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing what you say you are doing and getting the output that you say you are getting, then it can only be a bug in the XSLT processor.